# Firefox build "you must have 'rustc' in your path"?

Tags: linux-mint, compiling, firefox, configure

I'm trying to build Firefox 51 from source on Mint 17.

I already ran the boostrap script and it installed rust, but `./mach build` apparently can't find it?

The error is:

```
 0:03.58 checking for rustc... not found
 0:03.58 checking for cargo... not found
 0:03.58 ERROR: Rust compiler not found.
 0:03.58 To compile rust language sources, you must have 'rustc' in your path.
 0:03.58 See https//www.rust-lang.org/ for more information.
 0:03.58 
 0:03.58 You can install rust by running './mach bootstrap'
 0:03.58 or by directly running the installer from https://rustup.rs/
 0:03.58
```

But I already ran `./mach bootstrap` and it installed rust!

Now when I run `./mach bootstrap` again, it says:

```
Could not find a Rust compiler.

You have some rust files in /home/user/.cargo/bin
but they're not part of this shell's PATH.

To add these to the PATH, edit your shell initialization
script, which may be called ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile or
~/.profile, and add the following line:

    source /home/user/.cargo/env

Then restart your shell and run the bootstrap script again.
```

So I did that. `~/.profile` now has `source /home/user/.cargo/env` at the bottom. And I restarted the terminal. And `./mach bootstrap` and `./mach build` still can't find rust.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Rust manually seemed to fix the issue:

```
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh
```

Comment: had to install rustc and cargo from a ppa (following http://askubuntu.com/questions/321743/where-are-the-rust-aka-rust-lang-packages-for-ubuntu#624260)

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `source ~/.profile` worked for me since the bootstrap script had already appended the rustc path in my `~/.profile`.

In case the path is appended to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`, `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_profile` respectively should do the job.

If the path is not appended by the script to any of the files, you can append the path on your own to any of the three files (`export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"` is appended in my `~/.profile`) and do `source ~/.<respective file>`.